# Remove quotes from json array

Tags: java, json, gson, arrays

I have the following problem:

I have an ArrayList in Java.

I convert the ArrayList to string like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String feeds += gson.toJson(arrayList);
```

This is the result:

```
[{"status":"ERROR","position":"[48.2748206,8.849529799999999]"}]
```

But i need the following output:

```
[{"status":"ERROR","position": [48.2748206,8.849529799999999]}]
```

The Value of position should be without quotes. How can i realize that?

Many thanks in advance

Greets

Comment: so you want ERROR in quotes but position without them, I don't think it's possible. You can always remove quotes, or typecast it into a position(custom) object if you want.

Comment: Yes thats what I want.

Comment: As I mentioned, you will have to manually remove the quotes from position value and cast into some object which you wish. Can't be done directly with gson.

Comment: I don't understand it. Can you make an example?

Comment: The value would have to start out as a JSON array rather than a string.  In the source ArrayList it's apparently a string.

Comment: It would be great if you can share code for `arrayList` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the double quotes around position's value using `String#replaceAll()` method. Just create a regex and replace double quotes with empty sting.

Try with Positive Lookbehind and Positive Lookahead.

sample code:

```
String json = "[{\"status\":\"ERROR\",\"position\":\"[48.2748206,8.849529799999999]\"}]";
String regex = "(?<=\"position\":)\"|\"(?=\\}\\])";
System.out.println(json.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vT6lH0/2)

---

Try with grouping and substitutions as well.

sample code:

```
String json = "[{\"status\":\"ERROR\",\"position\":\"[48.2748206,8.849529799999999]\"}]";
String regex = "(\"position\":)\"([^\"]*)\"";
System.out.println(json.replaceAll(regex, "$1$2"));
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vT6lH0/3)

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you very much :-) One last queestion: How must the regex look like if the output looks like this: [{"status":"ERROR","position":"[48.2748206,8.849529799999999]","entityType":"hello"}] ?

Comment: check second option that looks for position value's double quotes. Test in demo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should go like this, may be you should change your work structure, But if you do want to typecast manually, then you can do it this way.
Suppose you have a JSONArray object like this:

```
JSONArray arr=[{"status":"ERROR","position":"[48.2748206,8.849529799999999]"}];
```

Then you can take out JSONObject like this:

```
Iterator iterator = array.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ClassToCastInto obj = gson.fromJson((JsonElement)iterator.next();, ClassToCastInto.class);
    System.out.println(obj.someProperty);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Gson [JsonWriter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html):

```
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(buffer);
    writer.beginArray().beginObject();
    writer.name("status").value("ERROR");
    writer.name("position").beginArray();
    for (double value : Arrays.asList(48.2748206, 8.849529799999999)) {
        writer.value(value);
    }
    writer.endArray().endObject().endArray().close();
    String json = buffer.toString();
```